# Node.js/MongoDB - "MongoError: topology was destroyed" - How do I solve this error when running this code in a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm super new to databases in general and decided to get started with MongoDB a few days ago. I've run into a problem I cannot find a solution to for the life of me (When I google this issue, people who have these issues are building full blown databases and applications, and the answers are super complicated in return -- I'm just over here trying to update a simple document more than once!)

So, when I run this code, it works PERFECT the first time it is run.
It runs smoothly, logs that the connection was successful, updates the document, returns the string saying it completed successfully, then logs that the disconnect was successful.

But when I run it a second time, I get this error from the debugger console:

```
(node:37908) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [servers] is not supported (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
warning.js:43(node:37908) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
warning.js:43(node:37908) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [dbName] is not supported
warning.js:43(node:37908) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [srvHost] is not supported
warning.js:43(node:37908) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [credentials] is not supported
```

and this error from the process console:

```
Connected correctly to server
MongoError: topology was destroyed
    at executeCommand (C:\Users\garre\Documents\_Random Projects\Discord Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\db_ops.js:222:21)
    at FindOneAndUpdateOperation.execute (C:\Users\garre\Documents\_Random Projects\Discord Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\find_and_modify.js:118:5)
    at C:\Users\garre\Documents\_Random Projects\Discord Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:72:19
    at maybePromise (C:\Users\garre\Documents\_Random Projects\Discord Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:692:3)
    at executeOperation (C:\Users\garre\Documents\_Random Projects\Discord Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:34:10)
    at Collection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\garre\Documents\_Random Projects\Discord Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1794:12)
    at Collection.deprecated [as findOneAndUpdate] (C:\Users\garre\Documents\_Random Projects\Discord Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:611:15)
    at run (C:\Users\garre\Documents\_Random Projects\Discord Bot\commands\databases\collectinfo.js:50:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Connection Closed
```

Here's the code that gets run every time I type -collectinfo in my channel (this is on a discord.js bot by the way).

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb+srv://private:private@private.wuiqr.mongodb.net/private?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const mongo = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

module.exports = {
    name: "collectinfo",
    description: "run the code below",
    cooldown: 1,
    execute(message) {

        let id = message.member.id;
        let name = message.member.user.username;

        async function run() {

            try {

                await mongo.connect();

                console.log('Connected correctly to server');

                let col = mongo.db('testDatabase').collection('timeTracking');

                // Find doc and update it, if it doesn't exist, create one (i think?)
                const myDoc = await col.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {
                        "_id": `${id}`
                    },
                    {
                        "$set": {
                            "_id": `${id}`,
                            "username": `${name}`,
                            "messages_sent": 1
                    }},
                    {
                        "upsert": true
                    }
                );

            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
            }
            finally {
                await mongo.close();
                await console.log("Connection Closed")
            }
        }
        run().catch(console.dir);
    },
};
```

So as you can see, everytime the command is run, everything in `execute(message){}` runs. The first time I run it, it goes just fine and works. The second time I run it, and every time after that -- fail.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to my issue.

I put all the require/const statements that were outside of the module function INSIDE of the execute() function.

```
module.exports = {
    name: "collectinfo",
    description: "run the code below",
    cooldown: 1,
    execute(message) {

        const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        const url = 'mongodb+srv://Desura72:golfer72@discordbotcluster.wuiqr.mongodb.net/testDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
        const mongo = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

        let id = message.member.id;
        let name = message.member.user.username;

        async function run() {

            try {

                await mongo.connect();

                console.log('Connected correctly to server');

                let col = mongo.db('testDatabase').collection('timeTracking');

                // Find doc and update it, if it doesn't exist, create one (i think?)
                const myDoc = await col.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {
                        "_id": `${id}`
                    },
                    {
                        "$set": {
                            "_id": `${id}`,
                            "username": `${name}`,
                            "messages_sent": 1
                    }},
                    {
                        "upsert": true
                    }
                );

            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
            }
            finally {
                await mongo.close();
                await console.log("Connection Closed")
            }
        }
        run().catch(console.dir);
    },
};
```

Turns out it only held onto these values the first time around for some reason.